# Columns are not on the same height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Hi I'm trying to get my columns on the same height. But here is a picture how I have ended:

[image]

I had tried to give `width` and `height` attributes of respectively 700 and 400 to my `img` tag. But this also didn't worked out. Here is a picture how I have ended:

[image]

And here is my piece of code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach ($projects as $project)
            <div class="col-lg-4 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="data:image/{{$project->image_type}};base64,{{$project->image}}">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#"> {{ $project->name }}</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            {!! $projects->render() !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple, you should add a `max-height` property to either the container of the image, or the image itself. The aspect ratio of the images varies, causing the images to become smaller (so they can maintain aspect ratio). Setting a `max-height` will prevent the image from scaling beyond the specified height.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the items into a [**flexbox**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes). Simply add the following class to the items parent, in this case `.row` :

```css
.equal-height {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="row equal-height">
  @foreach ($projects as $project)
  <div class="col-lg-4 portfolio-item">
    <a href="#">
       <img class="img-responsive" src="data:image/{{$project->image_type}};base64,{{$project->image}}">
    </a>
    <h3>
      <a href="#"> {{ $project->name }}</a>
    </h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p </div>
  </div>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

demo with your markup, have changed `.col-lg-4` to `.col-xs-3` so it fits into the fiddle result frame, but it does not make any difference -> **http://jsfiddle.net/63zvdLyu/**

Comment: I had done what you had asked. But it didn't worked out :(. Here is the result: http://i.imgur.com/pTRGyjr.png

Comment: @superkytoz, the boxes have equal height, I am sure - but your images are very different in height / size.  Perhaps this is your real problem?

Comment: That is indeed correct. This problem occurs, because my images are indeed different in height/size. But unfortunately I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Building on what @davidkonrad said, you could offset each image (inner-item) with a margin-top rule like this:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63zvdLyu/11/)

```
<div class="row equal-height">
    <div class="col-xs-3 portfolio-item">
        <div class="inner-item-1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 portfolio-item">
        <div class="inner-item-2">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </div>            
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 portfolio-item">
        <div class="inner-item-3">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.inner-item-1 {
    background-color: green;
    display: block; /* images are inline by default */
}
.inner-item-2 {
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-top: 100px;
    display: block; /* images are inline by default */
}
.inner-item-3 {
    background-color: blue;
    margin-top: 140px;
    display: block; /* images are inline by default */
}
.portfolio-item {
    border:1px solid red;
    padding: 0;
}
.equal-height {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
```